# read text file and store in array in c programming

Tags: c, file-io

I want read text file and store in array then show.

This is my code:

```
  int i = 0, line = 5;
  char ch[100];

  FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (myfile== NULL)
    {
    printf("can not open file \n");
    return 1;
    }

    while(line--){
    fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);
    i++;
    printf("\n%s", &ch[i]);
    }

    fclose(myfile);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my text:

test 123562

856

59986

But result:

est

2356

56

9986

What is wrong? :(

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code in the debugger line by line, while keeping track of `i`, `ch` and `&ch[i]`.

Comment: 1. `%s`  in `fscanf` breaks at space char; 2) you do `printf` after `i++`, i.e. show one char after scanned. It is better to use `fgets` insteaf of `fscanf` in your case.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>`ch[i]` is holding a single character. Statement `fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);` will scan string to `ch[i]` which can hold only one character. There is no place for `'\0'` which leads your program to **undefined behavior**. 
Change</strike>

```
fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);
```

to

```
fscanf(myfile,"%s",ch);
```

---

Previous answer was wrong. Behavior of program is well defined but you are scanning the file in a wrong manner. Your program will work as expected if you place `i++;` after `printf` statement.

```
while(line--){
    fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);
    printf("\n%s", &ch[i]);
    i++;
}
```

The reason is that `&ch[i]` is a pointer to the i<sup>th</sup> element of the array and string will be stored in array starting at position `i`. For the input given, this will work because the given array is large enough to hold the string.

You can do this as:

```
while(line--){
    fscanf(myfile,"%s",ch);
    printf("\n%s", ch);
    i++;
}
```

but it will overwrite the array `ch` each time a string is scanned to it. Better to use a two dimensional array to store strings and read file with `fgets`.

Comment: It would nice to explain that (s)he wants to scan for a string, not a single character.

Comment: The variable `i` is not needed in the first place.

Comment: tanks but i need access to my array. i need ch[0],ch[1],ch[2],.. for analyze

Comment: While `ch[i]` is only a single character, remember that `&ch[i]` is equivalent to `ch + i`, and when `i` is e.g. `0` then that's just plain `ch`. So `&ch[i]` is a pointer to a string that starts at index `i` in the array `ch`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; Yes. Point to be noted!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; My answer was wrong. Edited that. Thanks for the valuable comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to fit five lines in the single `char ch[100]` array; that's just an array of 100 characters.

You can make it an array of arrays, i.e. `char ln[5][100]` which will give you room for five lines of 100 characters each.

Then you of course need to index into that array in the loop, i.e.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  if(fgets(ln[i], sizeof ln[i], myfile) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Read error on line %d\n", i);
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

This uses [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) which is *much* better suited at reading in whole lines; `fscanf()` will stop at whitespace with `%s` which is seldom what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the ampersand in the scanf while getting the string. Make that into like this.

```
fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);
```

to

```
fscanf(myfile,"%s",ch);
```

`&ch[i]` It will get the character for i th position in that array. If you want to get like that you can use the `%c` instead of `%s`. And change this one to.

```
printf("\n%s", ch);
```

While printing the string when you use the ampersand(&) that will access the address of that variable.

Comment: Changing `fscanf(myfile,"%s",&ch[i]);` to `fscanf(myfile,"%s",ch);` will not solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

3. The program developed must be able to read the input files containing matrix A and matrix B
   using fopen function
   a. Matrix A and B of different size may be stored in different input file (if required).
4. Scan and assign matrix A and B as array using fscanf function and for loop
5. Perform matrix operations
   a. Add matrix A and B
   b. Subtract matrix A and B
   c. Multiply matrix A and B
6. Use conditional statement if or switch for switching between 3, 4 and 5 elements matrix.
7. Print all input matrices and results obtained in a new file called output.dat using fprintf
   function.
8. The output.dat file must have a header with the following information:
   a. Student name
   b. Student matric number
   c. Class section
   d. Lecturer name
   e. Project title
9. Below the header, the output file must contain matrix A and B and the results from matrix
   operation.
   Use matrix A and B as given below:

Comment: wheres 1 and 2?